# Is there a point listening to people talking among themselves?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When inside outposts, I often see people talk among themselves about various things.

So far when I listened it was about weather, or food, etc.

It's really boring so I didn't bother to listen much.

So, is there a point listening to that chatter? Can I get a side quest from it, or a hint for some good treasure?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

In FFXV this is equivalent to in past FF titles walking up to NPCs and pressing X to see what they had to say. It's usually just flavor text about the area or recent story events to make the world feel more alive. As far as treasure goes I haven't personally encountered a single case of this, however, in the story progression some NPCs give clues to where to go next.

As a side note it's possible to walk away and back to NPCs to get them to trigger a dialogue sequence, after a short while you will see they just repeat like past games.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought as well. Since this is "only" your personal observation I'll wait for other answers though, either to confirm this or disprove this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no worries, granted, if NPC dialogue was involved in some sort of reward there would be information about it out on the internet by now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a window in Lestallum, that - if you have unlocked the flying car after the storyline - allows you to overhear two guys talking. It gives you a quest for the Pitioss Ruins, that's the only quest from ambient dialogue I know of.

Comment: You're extremely hard to understand. Please try to use proper grammar. I have no idea what you want to say, because I would have to try to untangle your sentence just to get what you mean.